# Node Output from mongo db as a list of objects

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

```
{
    "dependencies" : [
        {
            "name" : "async",
            "version" : "2.6.1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "body-parser@1.18.3",
            "version" : "1.18.3"
        },
        {
            "name" : "cookie-parser@~1.4.3",
            "version" : "1.4.3"
        },
        {
            "name" : "debug@~2.6.9",
            "version" : "2.6.9"
        },
        {
            "name" : "express@~4.16.0",
            "version" : "4.16.4"
        },
        {
            "name" : "http-errors@~1.6.2",
            "version" : "1.6.3"
        },
        {
            "name" : "mongoose",
            "version" : "5.3.13"
        },
        {
            "name" : "morgan@~1.9.0",
            "version" : "1.9.1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "pug@2.0.0-beta11",
            "version" : "2.0.0-beta11"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

```
MongoDB Connected
[ { dependencies: 
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ] } ]
```

---

```
exports.repo_search = function(req, res, next) {
    Repo.findById(req.params.id).populate('repo').exec(function(err, repo) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (repo == null) {
            // No results.
            var err = new Error('Repo copy not found');
            err.status = 404;
            return next(err);
        }
        Dependencies.find({ Repo_id: '2' }, { dependencies: 1, _id: 0 }).exec(function(err, list_dependencies) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            console.log(list_dependencies);
            // Successful, so render.
            //res.render('dependencies_list', { title: 'Dependencies List', list_dependencies: list_dependencies });

            // Successful, so render.
            res.render('repo_info_detail', {
                title             : 'Repo Detail',
                repo              : repo,
                list_dependencies : list_dependencies

                //  repo_dependencies: results.repo_search
            });
            //  console.log(Repo._id);
        });
    });
};
```

Hi, I am using Node and Mongodb with mongoose. I am trying to output a list of dependencies. When i do a console log i get a dependencies list of objects that are called object. The command i am using outputs on the mongo cmd line but when i try to query it in node , and put a console log in my controller i get this. Anybody Know how to fix it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this,  `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list_dependencies)));` or use .toArray()

Comment: No still outputs list of objects. I thought that would work also

Comment: In the terminal, Objects will show like that if you want to see the full result. stringify the object `console.log(JSON.stringify(list_dependencies));`

Comment: Thanks Rahul That worked

Answer (score 0):

that's not contain problems with your code.

Try with

```
 console.log(list_dependencies[0]);
```

If not work, just change from string to object like this

```
const result = JSON.parse(list_dependencies);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB "find" query returns an array(list) of results.(you see a list of objects)

If you are are expecting only one result better use "findOne" query.